# DC or average value of a non-sinusoidal signal

Tags: integrated-circuit, dc, filter, low-pass

I need to find the DC value or the average value of the distorted waveform. First the waveform is given to op-amp voltage follower circuit to prevent it from loading and then to a RC low pass filter, but getting an error of around 10% (Comparing it with the DSO output).

Can someone suggest me a good circuit model for the same or any IC for this special purpose?

**Edit:** We don't need to find the RMS value here, for that case there is an IC AD736 for this special purpose. What we need is to calculate average value or DC value. Like the waveforms shown below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: AC couple it into one unity gain buffer. DC couple it into another. Subtract one from t'other. You may be able to press an InAamp (Instrumentation Amplifier into service for this.

Comment: How do you know you are getting an error of 10%? What are you comparing it to? What is the time constant of your averager? Give us more detail of the circuit and the signals.

Comment: You want the RMS value. There are circuits that do this, even using just opamps, no special chips required.

Comment: @Aaron - The RMS value is not the same as the average. Why do you say he wants RMS?

Comment: @KevinWhite I guess the OP needs to clarify what they want.  **DC value** is **RMS**.  But neither of those are the **average** for a distorted wave shape (which is not shown).

Comment: Please post an image or drawing of said non-sinusoidal, distorted waveform.

Comment: @Aaron - Not so - the DC value is the average. RMS would be the effective heating value. If the average was negative it would still have a positive RMS.

Comment: @KevinWhite We're both correct, depending on the actual wave form.  eg. RMS of a sine wave is the DC value.

Comment: @Aaron I think Kevin may have misspoke and that you are probably more correct in my view. The average value of a sine with no DC bias is always zero, for example. (Assuming the period of time is chosen, conveniently.) But it's \$V_\text{RMS}\$ is likely not zero. I do think that \$V_\text{DC}=V_\text{RMS}\$ in all cases, though. That is because I believe these two terms are intended to develop from a *power* perspective -- the ability to heat something. In short, \$V_\text{DC}=V_\text{RMS}=\sqrt{\frac1{T}\int_0^TV_t^2\:\text{d}t}\$. However, \$V_\text{AVG}=\frac1{T}\int_0^TV_t\:\text{d}t\$.

Comment: @Aaron The above also assumes ideal voltage sources, of course. (Their voltage doesn't depend upon the load they drive.) So, except in providential cases, \$V_\text{DC}\ne V_\text{AVG}\$ but always \$V_\text{DC}=V_\text{RMS}\$ since the latter is based upon an equivalent power perspective while the former is comparing two different concepts. Too bad the OP hasn't uttered so much as a peep in all this time!

Comment: @KevinWhite Thank you for your answer. I recently added some pictures, please go through them.

Comment: @jonk Sorry for the delay. I just added new information regarding the various waveforms.

Comment: @M.KamranIkram Yeah. But you probably didn't read my equations or else it's a language barrier issue. The average of something means one thing. The DC value another thing. The two are not the same. Define your meaning either with mathematics or else by taking a specific curve above and compute by hand a value for it so that we can replicate what you want to achieve.

Comment: @jonk - normally the DC value is the same as the average. If you pass the signal through a low pass filter so all AC components are removed you will be left with the DC component. This is identical to the average.

Comment: You may use A/D conversation and then use trapezoidal rule. Use Arduino and Matlab / Octave.

Comment: @jonk Thank you. But I need average value here, i.e., VAVG=1/T∫T0Vtdt

Comment: @KevinWhite I defined the average with math. If you have another definition and can express it in mathematical form, we can compare and discuss. I've been crystal clear in meaning by providing exact mathematical equations for their definitions. Otherwise, it's just a battle between ambiguous dictionary sentences and definitions of words, which don't really tell you what something actually *is*. There's a great story from Dr. Feynman on this topic, told early on in his biography, "The Beat of a Different Drum." But that's for another time. I believe it may apply pretty well here, though.

Comment: @M.KamranIkram Thanks. That's the definition of an average, agreed. You just need to convert the voltage to a current and integrate it into a capacitor, periodically (as appropriate) reseting it for the next integration period. Are you able to generate a pulse of some kind that delineates the period of integration you want? (It appears it could also be generated from your output, but if you already have something convenient, that would be nice, too.)

Comment: @M.KamranIkram - what is T in your equation"VAVG=1/T∫T0Vtdt"? Is that the period of the waveform? The integral is presumably over time 0 to 1/T.

Comment: @KevinWhite Yeah T=2pi i.e., period of waveform

Answer (score 2):

A lowpass filter can find it, for ex. a RC filter. But the result takes at least 5RC to get stabilized to 1% and it still has AC component, too because the filter doesn't fully attenuate the non-zero frequency components. A good idea to search a compromise between the unwanted AC component and the build-up time of the average is to simulate.

Another approach is an integrator+ a control circuit which resets the integrator, lets it get charged a certain time period (=integrator's time constant), changes the integrator to hold state (=removes the charging current) and outputs a signalling pulse "the average is now available at the output".

The described device can be considered as a measuring machine which should be triggered to make one measurement. If you have periodic signal to be measured you should extract the triggering and integration period from the signal or from the circuit which generates the signal for consistent results with low number of integrated periods.

Finally you can take samples with an AD converter to a computer and calculate the average over a certain time period with software.

BTW. Your drawn signal seems to be sinusoidal voltage, only a part of the period is forced to be zero like the output of a controlled rectifier. If you know the amplitude and the on-off switching angles you can calculate the average as elementary definite integral over the ON-part of the period divided by the length of the full period.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, you get it correctly it is the output of controlled rectifier. Can you suggest me some IC for this special purpose? Or some more advance filter to get the required output.

Comment: @M.KamranIkram - the low pass filter (even a simple RC) will give the correct average for a continuous repetitive waveform. It is the DSO that gives the error if it is not sampling a complete waveform. This is a typical signal sampling issue that will happen when you truncate a signal and do not let it extend to infinity. the usual problem is when doing an FFT that requires window function to give acceptable results.

Comment: I do not know a single off the shelf IC solution. You should define the wanted averaging principle to get detailed suggestions. Even the triggered averager is easy if you can extract a good quality clock from the AC, Specify the allowed time and ripple parameters for filtering.

Comment: Actually, I want a dc output of the time-average of the given waveform. And the waveform may get more distorted, due to the switching angle.

Comment: You have still given no timing specs? How long you can wait for reliable enough estimate is cumulated for ex?  Or do you need a new estimate after every cycle? Voltage, allowed error? Frequency range? How much noise there exists? Could you accept a rom which is a lookup table for DC vs angle assuming a constant amplitude? Know that engineering doesn't happen without numerical specs. You can have a crystal ball but most of us do not.

Answer (score 1):

The simple RC filter will give the long term average of the input signal.

The difference you are seeing between that and the DSO measurement is probably due to the way the DSO measures the average.

To find the mean level of a signal with a DSO you need to ensure either that the timebase is selected so there is an integral number of cycles on the screen or use the function in the DSO to do the mean over one cycle. If there is a fraction of a cycle being measured the result will be in error.

On my TDS3014 scope the two measurements are called "Mean", which will perform the average over the entire screen, and "Cycle Mean" that will perform the average over one complete cycle. There is also a "Cycle RMS" to measure the RMS value over one cycle.

For the diagrams you show the lower waveform is not shown correctly if it is intended to be repetitive. The first quarter-cycle at the right is missing.